# How to set props in Search form

Tags: reactjs, search

I am creating search component, but I have an issue with that. How can I get value from user when they enter from their board.
this is code search form component

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import "../Search/index.css";

const Search = ({ title }) => {
  return (
    <input
      type="search"
      className="search"
      placeholder="Search..."
      onChange={title}
    />
  );
}

Search.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string,
};

Search.defaultProps = {
  title: "",
};

export default Search;
```

This is where I display that

```
import React from "react";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import Search from "./components/Search/index"

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Container fluid>
      <Row>
        <Col><Search title="depend on user" /></Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I know that onChange is a function, how can I change for that.

My idea is that when the user enters, the value will show that much ie no need to press enter or a button at all.

Please, help me with this my section

Answer (score 0):

why are you passing on change from props manage it using state.

```
    import React from "react";
    import PropTypes from "prop-types";
    import "../Search/index.css";
    
    function Search() {
     let [searchString, setsearchString] = useState('');
     const handleChange = (e) => {
      setsearchString(e.target.value);
     }
      return (
        <input
          type="search"
          className="search"
          placeholder="Search..."
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={searchString}
        />
      );
    }
    
    export default Search;
```